# docker pull through cache for private registry not working

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I tried the pull through cache docker released in registry 2.1.1 release with docker 1.8. on CentOS7.1 However, I followed these websites and it doesn't act as mirroring, any inputs would be much appreciated. I hope this is the right way of configuring registry service and passing docker daemon arguments.

Websites: 
https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/mirror.md
http://docs.master.dockerproject.org/articles/registry_mirror/

Steps:

1. I added arguments to pass to docker daemon process and restarted it:

   ```
   # /etc/sysconfig/docker 
   # 
   # Other arguments to pass to the docker daemon process 
   # These will be parsed by the sysv initscript and appended 
   # to the arguments list passed to docker -d
   OPTIONS="--registry-mirror=http://localhost:5000"
   ```
2. Added registry config and mounted to the container:

   ```
   version: 0.1
   log:
     fields:
       service: registry
   storage:
       cache:
           blobdescriptor: inmemory
       filesystem:
           rootdirectory: /var/lib/registry
   http:
       addr: :5000
       headers:
           X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
   health:
     storagedriver:
       enabled: true
       interval: 10s
       threshold: 3
   proxy:
     remoteurl: https://registry-1.docker.io
   ```
3. Launched registry container

   ```
   docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry-mirror -v /opt/docker-registry/local/images:/var/lib/registry -v /opt/docker-registry/local/config/config.yml:/etc/docker/registry/config.yml -e STANDALONE=false -e MIRROR_SOURCE=https://registry-1.docker.io -e MIRROR_SOURCE_INDEX=https://index.docker.io registry:2.1.1
   ```
4. Tested pull through cache with commands as follows:

   With my mirror running, pull an image that I haven't pulled before (using time to time it)

   Pulls from docker hub as configured as MIRROR_SOURCE

   ```
   $ time docker pull busybox:latest
   ```

   Remove the image from local machine

   ```
   $ docker rmi busybox:latest
   ```

   Finally, this should re-pull the image from cache, which is not working in my case, rather pulling from docker hub instead.

   ```
   $ time docker pull busybox:latest
   ```

   I also tried looking at the mounted images volume folder in my host file system, couldn't find it.

   ```
   $ ls /opt/docker-registry/local/images/docker/registry/v2/repositories/
   ```

   Tried making rest api call to that new image, returns error message instead:

   ```
   $ curl http://localhost:5000/v2/busybox/tags/list     
       {"errors":[{"code":"NAME_UNKNOWN","message":"repository name not known to registry","detail":{"name":"busybox"}}]}
   ```

Comment: Does any one find any solution to this issue ? @doss.

Answer (score 3):

The API URL in the question is wrong. The correct one is:

```
$ curl http://localhost:5000/v2/library/docker/tags/list

{"name":"library/docker","tags":["1","1-dind","1-experimental","1-experimental-dind","1-e...
```

For images without the slash in the name, use the `library` prefix. If your registry is responding it should work.

In my example I'm running it this way:

```
docker run \
        -d \
        -p 5000:5000 \
        --restart=always \
        --name docker-through-cache \
        -v "$PWD/docker-proxy-config.yml:/etc/docker/registry/config.yml" \
        -v /var/docker-registry:/var/docker-registry \
        registry:2
```

Config:

```
version: 0.1
proxy:
  remoteurl: https://registry-1.docker.io
storage:
  filesystem:
    rootdirectory: /var/docker-registry
    maxthreads: 100
http:
  addr: 0.0.0.0:5000
log:
  accesslog:
    disabled: true
  level: info
  formatter: text
  fields:
    service: registry
```

Client config on my Ubuntu is in the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file:

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": ["http://127.0.0.1:5000"]
}
```

When your client is configured properly, the following logs would appear in the repository log:

```
time="2021-10-01T07:13:47.130717525Z" level=info msg="response completed" go.version=go1.11.2 http.request.host="127.0.0.1:5000" http.request.id=d9329952-12db-427e-b2c6-346aa8c96425 http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr="172.17.0.1:46142" http.request.uri="/v2/library/docker/blobs/sha256:f7a4137012260e097fc6b4bf6d75ba3b193acb399fb1276687303dea63ba519c" http.request.useragent="docker/20.10.8 go/go1.16.6 git-commit/75249d8 kernel/5.11.0-34-generic os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/20.10.8 \(linux\))" http.response.contenttype="application/octet-stream" http.response.duration=451.36281ms http.response.status=200 http.response.written=61283898
```

This particular log appears when your client downloads a layer (look at the blob hash):

```
$ docker pull docker:20.10.8-dind
20.10.8-dind: Pulling from library/docker
...
f7a413701226: Pull complete
...
```

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me using ...

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 \
    -e STANDALONE=false \
    -e MIRROR_SOURCE=https://registry-1.docker.io \
    -e MIRROR_SOURCE_INDEX=https://index.docker.io \
    -e "REGISTRY_LOG_LEVEL=debug" \
    -e "REGISTRY_REDIRECT_DISABLE=true" \
    -v /var/lib/registry:/var/lib/registry \
    --name registry-cache-latest \
    registry
```

.. and then pointintg --registry-mirror to the http server, not https.

Comment: Look that it is version 1, not version 2. I read that version 1 was a implementation in python. Insisting in version 2, what I was able to see in the logs was some bad certificate messages.